# Q > SQL Business days for specific month/region

Tags: sql, automation, ssms

I am trying to write a sql query that would automate my reporting, I am pulling total renewal volume for month X and dividing it by the # of business days for that specific month (manual process for now). The issue that I am having and cannot seem to solve is that I report on two centers (Toronto & Montreal) and these two cities do not share the same holidays so depending on the month the # of business days will vary between cities.

The solution that I can think of is making a table within sql manually with a year or two ahead of the holidays for these 2 cities then sourcing the table, unless anyone else can suggest something better :).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have faced this same problem, and you have the right idea. You need to make a table.

Comment: Yeah I went with making my own table, cheers!